# Nuxt3 build error when deploying with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuxt.js, aws-amplify, nuxt3

i use aws amplify to deploy the nuxt3 framework.
the build are okay, it not shown any error. bellow are the log

```
71f66f4e.mjs.map (2.91 kB) (879 B gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/ContentRenderer-71f66f4e.mjs (4.14 kB) (1.46 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/ContentQuery-ab673a1a.mjs.map (10.4 kB) (2.23 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/ContentQuery-ab673a1a.mjs (10.4 kB) (2.95 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/ContentNavigation-d9b677b2.mjs.map (58 kB) (4.3 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/ContentNavigation-d9b677b2.mjs (158 kB) (26.3 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/ContentList-0bb27936.mjs.map (2.35 kB) (755 B gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/ContentList-0bb27936.mjs (3.73 kB) (1.34 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/ContentDoc-6f479eaf.mjs.map (3.3 kB) (922 B gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/ContentDoc-6f479eaf.mjs (5.22 kB) (1.72 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/client-only-6cbaeabd.mjs.map (2.92 kB) (929 B gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/client-only-6cbaeabd.mjs (2.46 kB) (918 B gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/client-db-68f7aeab.mjs.map (14.2 kB) (3.32 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/client-db-68f7aeab.mjs (14.2 kB) (4.21 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/Button-f4409d41.mjs.map (3.22 kB) (963 B gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/Button-f4409d41.mjs (4.96 kB) (1.67 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/auth-be280cc0.mjs.map (1.16 kB) (461 B gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/auth-be280cc0.mjs (1.08 kB) (504 B gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/404-6d7523e2.mjs.map (1.71 kB) (671 B gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/404-6d7523e2.mjs (3.15 kB) (1.23 kB gzip)
                                     ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/_plugin-vue_export-helper-cc2b3d55.mjs.map (484 B) (295 B gzip)
                                     └─ .output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/_plugin-vue_export-helper-cc2b3d55.mjs (254 B) (200 B gzip)
                                     Σ Total size: 14.7 MB (2.94 MB gzip)
    2023-04-15T10:56:55.717Z [INFO]: [success] [nitro] You can preview this build using `node .output/server/index.mjs`
    2023-04-15T10:56:55.748Z [INFO]: Done in 33.88s.
    2023-04-15T10:56:55.752Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
    2023-04-15T10:56:55.754Z [INFO]: ## Build completed successfully
    2023-04-15T10:56:55.755Z [INFO]: # Starting caching...
    2023-04-15T10:56:55.765Z [INFO]: # Creating cache artifact...
    2023-04-15T10:57:05.286Z [INFO]: # Created cache artifact
    2023-04-15T10:57:05.439Z [INFO]: # Uploading cache artifact...
    2023-04-15T10:57:09.461Z [INFO]: # Uploaded cache artifact
    2023-04-15T10:57:09.560Z [INFO]: # Caching completed
    2023-04-15T10:57:09.567Z [INFO]: # No custom headers found.
    2023-04-15T10:57:09.600Z [WARNING]: !! No index.html detected in deploy folder: /codebuild/output/src412744304/src/main-landing-page/.output/server/
    2023-04-15T10:57:09.601Z [INFO]: # Starting build artifact upload process...
    2023-04-15T10:57:10.202Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifacts.zip'...
    2023-04-15T10:57:10.236Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifactsHash.zip'...
    2023-04-15T10:57:10.368Z [INFO]: # Build artifact upload completed
    2023-04-15T10:57:10.368Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
    2023-04-15T10:57:10.368Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
    2023-04-15T10:57:10.449Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
    2023-04-15T10:57:10.450Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
    Terminating logging...
```

and this is my AWS Amplify Build Settings

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .output/server/
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

i use base directory to *.output/server* based on this document
because when i use *dist* or */dist* it shown error the foldern ot found
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#supported-hosting-providers

---

The Build Are succesful but when i try to visit the link it just show *http error 404*

[image]

The build spec are using node version 16

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the output directory correct but Nuxt 3 `npm run generate` doesn't output an index.html, so double check your Amplify project **Rewrites and redirects** so that 200.html is the default web page and 404.html is your 404

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your AWS build config file to something like this.

```yaml
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn generate 
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .output/public
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Works with NPM also.